# Отдельная таблица для каждой строки в основной таблице

Tags: sql, база-данных, архитектура

Мне нужно хранить в БД список товаров:

- товар1, ..., товарN
- для каждого товара нужно хранить список покупок (когда и кокое количество товара покупалось)

Правильно ли будет сделать следующим образом?

1. создать одну основную таблицу, содержащую список товаров (товар1, ..., товарN) и информацию по ним
2. для кадого товара создать отдельную таблицу, в которую будут добавляться покупки

(т.е. всего будет N+1 таблиц)

Answer (score 2):

Это всего 2 таблицы: товаров и покупок.

В таблице покупок колонка -- ссылка на товар.

Comment: Да, можно так сделать. Спасибо. Но мне кжется удобнее с отдельными таблицами.

Comment: 0) чем оно удобнее? 1) и как вы будете посылать запросы? 2) Создание таблицы -- DDL – Data Definition Language (язык описания данных). select, insert -- DML – Data Manipulation Language (язык манипулирования данными).
DDL, как минимум не транзакционен.

Comment: По сути дела у меня вся аналитика будет по отдельным товарам, т.е. мне по сути дела нужны просто N таблиц (каждая таблица анализируется отдельно от других). Запросы мне нужны, например, такие: просмотреть покупки конкретного товара за период времени (с такой-то даты по такую-то). Может мне опыта не хватает, но я не вижу чем мой подход плох. Если не сложно объясните подробнее. Сразу две таблицы будет затрагивать только процесс добавления нового товара (добавление строки в основную таблицу и создание отдельной таблицы для нового товара).